# C# Using a single event for increment and decrement

Tags: c#, events

I have a recursive function and two events (`Going_in` and `Coming_out`).

I use the `Going_in` event to increment a progressbar every time the function calls itself and I use `Coming_out` to decrement the progressbar every time the function returns from recursion.

Now i have to combine `Going_in` and `Coming_out` into one event.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Here is part of the code.

Form1.cs

```
   .....
   void ProgressBar_increment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value++;

    }
    void ProgressBar_decrement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value--;
    }
   public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        initialize();
        label3.Visible = false;
        int wait_time = telltime();
        int number = reading();

        Facto mth;


        mth = new Facto(label3, wait_time, progressBar1);

        mth.Going_in += new EventHandler(ProgressBar_increment);
        mth.Coming_out += new EventHandler(ProgressBar_decrement);


        int result = mth.Factorial(number);

        string display = result.ToString();


        label3.Visible = true;

        label3.Text = display;
    }
```

Facto.cs

```
public event EventHandler Going_in;
public event EventHandler Coming_out;

........

public int Factorial(int number_to_calculate)
    {


        int Result;

        if (Going_in != null)
        {
            Going_in(this, new EventArgs());
        }


         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(wait_time);
        if (number_to_calculate == 0)
        {
            if (Coming_out != null)
            {
                Coming_out(this, new EventArgs());
            }

            return 1;

        }
        else
       {
           Result = (number_to_calculate * Factorial(number_to_calculate - 1));
           if (label_for_output != null)
           {
               label_for_output.Visible = true;
               label_for_output.Text = Result.ToString();
               label_for_output.Update();
           }
           else 
               Console.WriteLine(Result);

       }


        if (Coming_out != null)
        {
            Coming_out(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(wait_time);



        return Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what the `EventArgs` are for.
Put some variable in the `EventArgs` object (or create your own for this purpose) from where you can determine whether to increment or decrement (`enum` maybe?)

I.e. (possible pseudo code alert)

```
if (Going_in != null)
{
   CustomEventArgs cea = new CustomEventArgs();
   cea.Type = Type.Decrement;
   Going_in(this, cea);
}
```

And in your event do something like:

```
void ProgressBar_DoProgress(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
 {
    if(e.Type == Type.Increment)
       progressBar1.Value++;

    if(e.Type == Type.Decrement)
       progressBar1.Value--;
 }
```

Comment: i get 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Type'. what am I missing?

Comment: @robertpas please note the pseudo code alert. If you look closely you see that I am using a CustomEventArgs. Which is non-existent. You would have to create your own CustomEventArgs object (derived from EventArgs and with a more descriptive name probably) and create a custom enum which in my code is called Type (again more descriptive name would be nice) and has the members Increment and Decrement to identify what you would want to do. The code above will not work out of the box without you creating your custom classes.